# SQL odd space characters

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an odd space character when copying from AD to my PhP/MySQL database.
When copying/pasting the "valid to" field from a published certificate in AD into a PhP/HTLM form field to post into a MYSQL database.

The test I am copying is ‎Friday, ‎March ‎3, ‎2017 3:37:42 PM.
It is coming out as â€ŽFriday, â€ŽMarch â€Ž3, â€Ž2017 3:37:42 PM','03/09/2015 15:28:19 and killing my script.

My PHP:

```
$TICKET     = $_POST["ticket"];
$DETAIL     = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["detail"]);
$DESCRIPTION = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["description"]);
$DETDATE    = $_POST["detdate"];
$DETFROM    = $_POST["detfrom"];
$UPDATE     = date("m/d/Y H:i");
$ADD_det_SQL = "INSERT INTO details (ticket,detail,date,detfrom,description) VALUES ('$TICKET','$DETAIL','$DETDATE','$DETFROM','$DESCRIPTION')";
$UPDATE_date_SQL = "UPDATE Tickets SET `update` = '$UPDATE' WHERE ticket = '$TICKET'";
IF (mysqli_query($link, $UPDATE_date_SQL) === TRUE){}
```

Result: 
`INSERT INTO details (ticket,detail,date,detfrom,description) VALUES ('IM3964078','â€ŽFriday, â€ŽMarch â€Ž3, â€Ž2017 3:37:42 PM','03/09/2015 15:28:19','V-FREDW','Test')`

Expected:
`INSERT INTO details (ticket,detail,date,detfrom,description) VALUES ('IM3964078','Friday, March 3. 2017 3:37:42 PM','V-FREDW','Test')`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this while I was getting ready to post it. The problem was in the Collation. It was set to Latin something or other. I set it to UTF8 - Default and it came out as I was expecting.